# How can I check if the values of multiple cells are equal?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, equality, worksheet-function

Let's say I have 6 different cells (that are not all in a line). I want to check if the values in these cells are equal. How could I do this with a function? I'd want the function simply to display "EQUAL" or "NOT EQUAL" (or maybe change the cell background color?).

Comment: A1 = B1 = C1 = D1 = E1 and so on... This will result a TRUE if all matches or a FALSE. (change range as required)

Comment: @Vasim - you cannot use several `=` signs like this. `=A1=B1=C1` would yield FALSE even if values in those cells were equal.

Comment: why it's about formula?

Answer (score 34):

One option for 6 cells would be this:

```
=IF(AND(A1=B2,B2=C3,C3=D4,D4=E5,E5=F6),"EQUAL","NOT EQUAL")
```

Another option - this way you don't need to reference the same cell twice:

```
=IF(AND(ARRAYFORMULA(A1={B2,C3,D4,E5,F6})),"EQUAL","NOT EQUAL")
```

---

If you wanted to color some cells if values in these cells are equal, you would need to create a Conditional Formatting rule with a similar formula:

1. Select the cells you want to color
2. Format > Conditional Formatting
3. Select "Custom formula is"
4. Fill in one of the above formulas without the `IF` part of formula, e.g.
   `=AND(ARRAYFORMULA(A1={B2,C3,D4,E5,F6}))`
5. Select the formatting style (color)
6. Done

Comment: for me, this didn't work, `A1={B2,C3,D4,E5,F6}` gives syntax error, but `A1={B2;C3;D4;E5;F6}` doesn't

Comment: @YakovL - it must be your locale. All basic formulas for you will require `;` instead of `,` which does not invalidate the answer.

Comment: oh my, formula syntax depends on locale.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 18):

as formula for conditional formatting:

```
=countunique({A1,B2,C3,D4,E5,F6})=1
```

as function it would be similar: `=if([formula],"EQUAL","NOT EQUAL"):`

**update:** the requested clarification:

- put the wanted cells in a custom array `{A1,B2,C3,D4,E5,F6}`
  (delimiters: `,` = new column, `;` = new row; for countunique either is fine)
- get the unique values `countunique(...)`
- if the outcome is 1 then all values are the same

**update 2**: original answer used `=count(unique(...))` instead of the combined function `=countunique(...)`

Comment: This is the best answer if you have blank cells in your range that you don't want to count as "Not Equal".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option without using an array that is easier to implement for large numbers of cells:

```
=IF(MIN(A1,B2,C3,D4,E5,F6)=MAX(A1,B2,C3,D4,E5,F6),"Equal", "Not Equal")
```

Comment: If you need to ignore #N/A: `=MINIFS(A1:F1,A1:F1,"<>#N/A")=MAXIFS(A1:F1,A1:F1,"<>#N/A")`