# check if all values returned in filter are equal (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a row with the following values in each cell from A1 until F1

```
A,A,A,A,A,A
```

Then in row 2 I have

```
A,B,A,A,A,A
```

Since some columns are empty (no value) I filter the row to get only cells with value:

```
=filter(A1:F1, A1:F1<>"")
```

then how can i get a true/false response if all values/strings in the filter array are equal?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47866850/4294399), but that was for a set of arbitrary cells, not a range.

Using range notation:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(A1:F1)=1
```

As implied by the function name, it counts the number of unique values. If there is only one unique value, then we know all the cells are equal. Since `COUNTUNIQUE` disregards blank values, there is no need to use `FILTER` first. If you want `TRUE` for all blanks, change `=` to `<=`, as it will return 0 in that case.

If you later decide you *do* want to consider blank values:

```
=COLUMNS(UNIQUE(A1:F1, 1))=1
```

This counts the number of columns returned by `UNIQUE(..., 1)` (`1` means "by column"). If it's 1, then all cells are equal.